# Problem with deploying QWebSocket project with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, openssl

I'm using [QWebSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html) to connect to a server that uses SSL, when I compile and run the program in Qt Creator on Windows 10 all works fine, but when I deploy the program I get a missing SSL error:

```
qt.network.ssl: No functional TLS backend was found
qt.network.ssl: No TLS backend is available
```

So I put `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to the same directory as the exe file but it didn't solve anything, same with adding OpenSSL dir to the system path. After adding `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to the directory with exe, the program shows missing SSL even in Qt Creator.
So it seems like Qt Creator uses different OpenSSL dependencies. So how to check which dependencies Qt Creator uses for OpenSSL?

Comment: how did you deploy your program? and did you install OpenSSL in windows? If your OS is **windows** you should install [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Comment: The problem was caused by libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll compiled under msvc2017, and i compiled my program with msvc2019 and Qt6